# doctrine 2, unable to insert to database when relation is present

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have two entites:

1) Service

```
/**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(length=255) */
    private $name;

    /** @Column(length=255) */
    private $description;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $parent;


    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Lead", mappedBy="service",cascade={"persist"})
     **/
    protected $leads;
```

2) Lead

```
/**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $user_id;

    /** @Column(name="service_id", type="integer") */
    private $service_id;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $lead_sent;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $date_created;


    /** @Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) */
    private $date_sent = null;

    /** @Column(type="integer", nullable=true) */
    private $size;

    /** @Column(type="text", nullable=true) */
    private $comment;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $estimate_date;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $source_zip;

    /** @Column(type="integer", nullable=true) */
    private $destination_zip;

    /** @Column(type="integer", nullable=true) */
    private $parent_lead;


    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="leads")
     * * @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $service;
```

When doing select:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT l FROM  Entities\Lead l 
                                            LEFT JOIN l.service s
                                            WHERE l.user_id='".$user_id."' ");
        $leads = $query->getResult();

        return $leads;
```

everything is great when I am doing select but when doing insert I am getting error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'service_id' cannot be null
```

I guess this would be case also for update.

This error is ok, because service_id can not be null.

This is my insert code:

```
$service = $this->em->getRepository("Entities\Service")->findBy(array("id"=>$data['master-service-id']));
$lead = new Entities\Lead;
$lead->setUser_id($this->user->getId());
$lead->setLead_sent(0);
$lead->setDate_created(new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
$lead->setDate_sent(new DateTime(date('0000-00-00 00:00:00')));
$lead->setService_id($service[0]->getId());
if($data['commnet']){
$lead->setComment($data['commnet']);
}
$lead->setSource_zip($data['zip']);
if($data['target_zip']){
$lead->setDestination_zip($data['target_zip']);
}
$lead->setEstimate_date(new DateTime($data['date']));

$this->em->persist($lead);
$this->em->flush();
```

Please help.

Comment: When I add /** @Column(name="service_id", type="integer", nullable=true) */
    private $service_id; it is working but I do not want that to be null. In post i have all data that I need and that service_id is never null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem starts here:

```
/** @Column(name="service_id", type="integer") */
private $service_id;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="leads")
 * @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $service;
```

**Never** map a single db column as *both* `@Column` *and* `@ManyToOne` (or `@OneToOne`)! Doctrine2 will behave erratic when you do this, so you must choose between a regular column, or an association.

In this particular case I'd advise you to choose an association, so remove the @Column. Only use this part:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="leads")
 * @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $service;
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$service = $em->getRepository('Service')->find(1);

$lead = new Lead();
$lead->setService($service);

$em->persist($lead);
$em->flush();
```

Doctrine2 will make sure the primary key of the Service table will be used as foreign key (service_id) in the Lead table.

Comment: I need /** @Column(name="service_id", type="integer") */
private $service_id; If I remove this that means I remove column from table. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Like you probably figured out: In your entity you need the association $service, in your db table you need the column 'service_id'.

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand this. After a lot of googling I did this for insert:

```
1. $service = $this->em->getRepository("Entities\Service")->find($data['master-service-id']);
2. $lead->setService($service);
3. $lead->setService_id($data['master-service-id']);
```

I do not understand why do I have to do

`$lead->setService($service); //this is from service entity`

This is from mysql query log when I do $lead->setService($service); adn flush after that :

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.description AS description3, t0.parent AS parent4 FROM services t0 WHERE t0.id = '5'
    924 Query   START TRANSACTION
    924 Query   INSERT INTO leads (user_id, service_id, lead_sent, date_created, date_sent, size, comment, estimate_date, source_zip, destination_zip, parent_lead) VALUES (19, 5, 0, '2013-04-30 19:53:48', '-0001-11-30 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, '2013-05-18 00:00:00', '21000', NULL, NULL)
    924 Query   commit
```

Any comment/answer is appreciated.

Comment: -1 for accepting your answer which a) you state yourself you don't understand and b) is incorrect.

Comment: this works for me, and also $lead->setService($this-em->getReference("Entities\Service",$data['master-service-id'] )); works for me. so your -1 is totally inappropriate. if you know better please add comment.