# How to use the cascade option in Doctrine2 to have associated entities automatically persisted?

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

Can someone explain me this:

```
$user = new User();

/* why do I have to call Entity Comment while trying to insert into db?  */
$myFirstComment = new Comment();

$user->addComment($myFirstComment);

$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($myFirstComment);
$em->flush();
```

Why do I have to call Entity Comment while trying to insert into db?

I have cascade for that.

1. Does this mean that if I have 50 relation in User Entity with other
   entities I have to call each relation manually when trying to
   update/insert/delete?
2. Why does cascade exist if I have to do all manually?

If I have to call all that relation manually it is kind of stupid to use Doctrine at all.

I do not get this. Any help is appreciated.

This is connected with this: [doctrine 2, unable to insert to database when relation is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305633/doctrine-2-unable-to-insert-to-database-when-relation-is-present)

Comment: I another words, Why do I have to call reference to other entity if I have cascade?

Comment: Long story short:

If I have association from one entity to another I have to call always that other entity on inserts/updates.

I can not say $user->addComment("some comment"), i have to call relation and then to do $user->addComment("some comment").

Thats make sense but it is kind of stupid. What if I have 50 relations? To call each relation on insert/update?

Doctrine is great for select but it sucks for everything else if you have relations.

I have to do 50 times $this->em->getReference('entity name') .....

Comment: i have answered your question with a lot of explanation and the hint to the documentation + attached a code exmaple. please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 19):

To have Doctrine automatically handle  the persistence of your `User#comments` property you have to set cascade to the "persist" operation.

The cascade ( persist, remove , merge, all ) option gives you the ability to ommit ...

```
$em->persist($myFirstComment);
```

... if you set it correctly on your inverse side of a bidirectional relation for example. 
It can also automatically remove `User#comments` if you remove a User entity with cascade "remove" !

example:

```
/**
 * Bidirectional - One-To-Many (INVERSE SIDE)
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="author", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $comments;
```

Read more on Association mapping and cascade in the [Transistive Persistence / Cascade Options](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) chapter of the documentation.

Please remember:

**Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.**

Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored. Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)

- OneToMany associations are never the owning side.
- The inverse side has to use the `mappedBy` attribute of the OneToOne, OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The `mappedBy` attribute contains the name of the association-field on the owning side
- The owning side has to use the `inversedBy` attribute of the OneToOne, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The `inversedBy` attribute contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.
- ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association.
- OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association.

Furthermore:

you only have to call persist if you create a new root entity ( i.e. `$user = new User()` ) which is not already managed by doctrine ( and you don't have to call persist on `$myFirstComment` in your example if you have set the cascade option correctly ).

Otherwise you only have to call flush if the entity hasn't for some reason been detached.

Comment: Since cascade operations watches only on owning side changes - can you please explain the difference of setting cascade operation on owning side and on iverse side? Both of sides has cascade option and I dont undestand why if there are only one watching side.