# Save related Object Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have User and Posts. One To Many

//user.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="posts")
 */
private $posts;

public function __construct () {
    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

post.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
 */
private $posts;
```

controller

```
$post->setPosts($this->getUser());
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
```

I have to use setPosts for persist related user? Can I save with cascade or something of this?

I know that

> There are two kinds of cascades in Doctrine:
>
> 1) ORM level
>
> 2) Database level

But I don't understand when use `cascade={"persist"})`

My questions are:

- How can I save user related from post object?
- When and Why use
  `cascade={"persist"})`?

**update**

I tried

//user

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="posts",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $posts;
```

controller

```
 $user = $this->getUser();
 $user->addPost($post);
 $em->persist($user);
 $em->flush();
```

But doesn't works, the field user_id in database is empty

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the cascade option in doctrine2 to have associatied entities automatically persisted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700338/how-to-use-the-cascade-option-in-doctrine2-to-have-associatied-entities-automati)

Comment: I saw, but I don't understand if my way is correct ( `$post->setPosts($this->getUser());`). I'm trying to use cascade, but doesn't work

Comment: You don't have cascade persist in your example code. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @OIS I updated my question. in my case the  the owning side is User ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entities should look like this :

**User.php**

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $posts;

    public function addPost(Post $post) {
        $post->setUser($this); // Call Post's setter here
        $this->$posts[] = $post; // Add post to the collection
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
class Post {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private $user;

    public function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user; // Set post's author
    }
}
```

In that case, you could use `cascade` if you are creating the user and its posts at the same time : you want to persist both the user and the posts, and attach the posts to the user.

If the user already exists at time you're persisting the post, you just have to set the post's author and persist the latter :

**Controller.php**

```
public function editPostAction() {
    // ...
    $post->setUser($this->getUser());
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();
    // ...
}
```

By the way, in a One-To-Many relation, the owning side is the Many side, Post in this case.

Comment: The one with inversedBy is the owning side. Accoring to this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: @monkeyUser `cascade` could be on both side of the relation, depends on what you're trying to achieve. In the code you gave `$post->setPosts($this->getUser());` why would you pass a `User` to a `setPosts` method ? Typically, you want to use cascade when you have embed forms, like if you had tags entity attached to your post, you might want to perform a cascading persist when you persist the post, so tags are persisted as well.

Comment: @OIS exactly, so the Many side owns the relation because it's the one that will own the foreign key in the database. Still, quoting Doctrine's doc `ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association.`

Comment: @paulgv thanks for reply, then for save my user_id in Post Table, I have not to use cascade, but can I do `$post->setPosts($this->getUser());` and then persist Post. otherwise how can I Save user_id in Post table?

Comment: Well, if the user already exists when you persist the post, all you have to do is call Post's setter `$post->setUser($this->getUser()); $em->persist($post); $em->flush();`.

Comment: @paulgv yes, user already exists (sorry I missed ). Instead if I have New User and New Post, I can use Cascade? sorry for my question loop

Comment: Yes, if you're creating the user AND the posts in the same form, you want to use cascade because you need the user to be persisted first and then the posts to be persisted along, with the newly persisted user as their author.

Comment: Perfect, I thought even with only New Post..Thank you for your Time

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $posts;
```

So all `$em->persist($user);` does is tell the entity manager that it should be managing $user. An entity being managed just means that when you call `$em->flush()` it will save that entity in its current state to the database, either by creating a new row in all the tables required, or updating the existing ones.

So to actually answer your question.
By adding the cascade={"persist"} to this annotation, the entity manager knows that if this User object is being managed, when a flush call is made, it will also need to perform whatever cascade operations you have defined for all Post objects associated with this User, and save their changes (or create new rows as required) to the database (or delete if you have cascade delete and remove a post from this user's post collection).

Comment: But in my case i Have to use `$post->setPosts($this->getUser());`for save related user

Comment: If I try your solution and add `$user->addPost($post); $em->persist($user)` I have this error User#posts' that was not configured to cascade persist