# Symfony cascade update to a parent relation

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I have a parent class A with relation oneToMany to class B (cascade persist)

I want to update A when B is updated (in a classic form/controller).

my problem is when I do something like this in B

$thisB->getParentA()->updateStuff()

the A modifications arent persisted...
i dont know how to deal with it.

Comment: We won't be able to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: I dont want a code I want a method ;)

Comment: I don't want to give you a code. I want you to give us your code to let us give you a method. ;-) Basically if you're dealing with entities fetched from DB, then they are managed entities which means they are observed by Doctrine and are updated in DB on `flush()` call even if `persist()` was not called before. So it looks like you're not telling us something that you might think it's not important or you have some bug in your code.

Comment: No bugs, it works very well but I dont know if it is possible to update a parent entity from a child one when it is updated. thats all really.

Comment: Yes, it is. It should work just as you described you're doing.

Comment: I think parent is already persisted or not persisted again after the child update the parent content

Comment: I'm not able to tell you anything more without seeing your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707937/181801). Your B entity is probably not the owning side of the relation so it is not checked.

From the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side):

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for
>   changes.
>
> OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association.

So you should probably call EntityManager::persist() on A to get it working.

Comment: A and B are updated when I submit modifications on each. But I cant modifiy A from B when just B is modified.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from calling persist($thisB->getParentA()) on the entity manager manually.

Comment: it is precisely what I do as I wrote, ...which does not work